# Does this math manipulation program exist already?

Tags: python, math

I do a *ton* of pencil and paper math for my job, which can get annoying and hard to keep track of. And I haven't had a fun programming project in a while, so I thought of something, and want to know if it exists yet.

I want to create an algebra manipulation program, where I can move pieces of the equation around with my mouse, and it displays the change immediately, and the program is intuitive. For example, I if I had (ax^3 + a^2*y^4), I could drag one of the a's outside of the parenthesis and it would know to turn it into a(x^3 + a*y^4).

Just to be clear: I'm *not* trying to make something that solves an equation analytically. I know Mathematica and a million other programs do that. In the thing I'd like to make, you'd still be solving it (often I'm not even "solving" something per se, really just trying to get it into a "pleasing form". Which isn't something a program can really do).

I've checked out MathCAD and it seems cool, but still not like what I'm talking about. I've checked out sympy as well (and I may end up using it if I make this) but it still doesn't have what I'm talking about.

So, does anyone know if this exists already? I'd like to do it but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thank you!!

Comment: Possibly one of the `maxima` GUIs? wxmaxima springs to mind. It may or may not be GUI, but it certainly has tools for expanding and factoring algebraic equations. (The magic Google words are probably "computer algebra system".)

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I downloaded wxmaxima and it seems like it can do some neat stuff, but not exactly what I'm talking about. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't believe it already exists. If you wanted to do it yourself, you could probably use a CAS like Maxima as a starting point - the hard part of the problem is implementing the computer algebra system.

Comment: I don't know of one, and it does seem like it would be useful; it could keep track of assumptions made in the manipulation - if you divided b/s of an inequality by a variable it could store the assumption that the variable is not negative, etc.

Comment: I think it would be VERY useful. I think I'm gonna do this, using support from other similar open source programs. Just to make absolute sure, no one else knows if this exists?

Comment: Neat idea.  Fun to play around with; helpful for teaching.  I can totally see it being a dorky but fun video game.

Comment: I don't believe this exists yet, but the best tools to build it are sympy and pyQt.

Answer (score 8):

There are several Mac apps that can do this.

The oldest is ["Graphing Calculator"](http://www.pacifict.com/Products.html), which used to come free with the Mac OS and has an interesting [genesis story](http://www.pacifict.com/Story/).It still lives on and now and has a Windows version, but for some inexplicable reason the developers seem to have a deliberate campaign to minimise their sales by having an extraordinarily unattractive website and no real free download version - though you can download a free "viewer" app that will show you some of what it can do, and if you stop the rolling demo it will let you manipulate the equations in the way you describe.

You can buy a "lite" version of Graphing Calculator from the [Mac App store](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/graphing-calculator-lite/id435943749?mt=12) which will easily do everything you need, as well as a cut down version which looks like it does all the algebraic manipulation stuff with out graphing called ["Equation Calculator"](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/equation-calculator/id437390502?mt=12).

Comment: Thank you! This is about exactly what I'm talking about, but do you know if it can do slightly more complicated algebraic expressions or just division and stuff? Also, this still may be worth doing, to have an open source version.

Comment: I'm not totally sure about the limits of its algebra abilities, but they're far beyond mine! It's certainly able to do much more than just division and stuff. As a quick test I tried dragging some things around in some of the demo equations and sines and cosines appeared where there were none before, so I suspect it has fairly deep mathematical knowledge, it's not just doing string manipulation. As I mentioned before, you can download the "viewer" program for free and it will run through a rolling demo. If you stop the demo at any point it'll let you manipulate the equations.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look also at http://equation.sourceforge.net/ (formerly MathDrag'n) and http://www.livemath.com/ (formerly Theorist) which have similar functionality.

Comment: Also look at "Drag to Solve" in Maple 16: http://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/new_features/clickablemath.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on an open source implementation of MathCad, called [Miramath](http://sourceforge.net/apps/gallery/miramath/index.php), using PyQt, Ply, Scipy, Sympy and Qwt.

> [image]

It is still in proof of concept mode, but all of the basic pieces are kind of there now. I did it to teach myself a bit of Python. The editor would need some work to support drag and drop features. Right now I don't have time to work on it.

Comment: The screenshots are proof of an excellent job done! Unfortunately I have to use MathCAD at work due to it's "write math like on a sheet of paper" feature (which my boss likes). So any (hopefully more stable) alternative would be very welcome here!